# Codeigniter 3 MY_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have this on my MY_Controller that was located on my core folder.

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_logged_in($data){    
        $session = $this->session->userdata();
        if($session['isloggedin']['username'] == ''){ 
        return isset($session); 
        }else{ 
        return FALSE;}  
    }
}
?>
```

I'm pretty sure i copy pasted the above code from some tutorial and i haven't gotten to editing it based on my needs.

Any case i have questions.

So i have a pages controller that will be responsible for giving access to some views depending on the account_type of the logged in user.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class pages extends MY_Controller {


}?>
```

this is my session whenever a user logs in.

```
    $new_session = array( 'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                          'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                          'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
                          'logged_in' => TRUE);
    $this->session->set_userdata($new_session);
```

How do i call the MY_controller function `is_logged_in()` from the pages controller or is the 'extends MY_Controller' automatically also calls the function `is_logged_in()` or do i have to basically just put it in a `__construct` so it automatically calls the function?

Also, how do i go about checking if a user is logged in and seeing their details?

Do i pass session_data from my controller to MY_Controller? if so, how?

Or should i just put a `$this->session->userdata();` line inside the `is_logged_in()` function?

P.S. i have tried using Authentication Libraries but they include far too much to what i need, i just need a basic authentication. Any suggestions? that is still maintained right now.

Answer (score 2):

you can directly call is_logged_in() function from your pages controller. just like this:

**Pages.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct() {
       parent::__construct(); // this will trigger the __construct() of MY_Controller 
    }

}
```

**MY_Controller.php**

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      if( $this->is_logged_in() ) {
         // do something if user is allowed to access.
      }
      else {
        // do something if user is not allowed to access
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, so the extends means i can call the function of my controller?

My impression was that whenever i load pages controller it would automatically load MY_controller. guess i was wrong.

Comment: Is my is_logged_in function okay? coz i feel like it has many redundancies, like the $data parameter, why pass $data to check for authenticity if i can just $session->userdata() in the function itself?

also the If and isset,